# C# how to change multi language in all windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, multilingual

C# how to change multi language in all windows form?

I use this method to change other language, but it only change current windows form.

I want to be choosing one language for all windows form. Thanks for answering.

Here is my code:

```
        private void ChineseTToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("zh-tw"); ;
    }

    private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("en");
    }

    private void ChineseSToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("zh-cn");
    }

    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FormMain));
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Iterate Application.OpenForms to find all opened forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make the `ChangeLanguage` method to allow calling it on any control or form.
Here is a version which is recursive and which takes a `Control` as a parameter.

Note: `Forms` are `Controls`, too.

So you can call this method to change all forms you have a handle of..

```
public ComponentResourceManager resources;

private void ChangeLanguage(Control ctl, string lang)
{
    resources.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
    foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls) ChangeLanguage(c, lang);
}
```

Next you need to keep a list of your open forms in some way. A `List<Form>` is a good way.

Instead of calling the `ChangeLanguage` function on only the current window you call a `ChangeLanguageOnAllforms` function. So if you have maybe a `List<Form>` called `myFormsList` you can do:

```
void ChangeLanguageOnAllforms(  string lang )
{
  foreach (Form f in myFormsList) 
  {
     if (f != null)
     { 
        resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(f));
        ChangeLanguage(f, languageString);
     }
  }
}
```

You should also keep a public variable to hold the current language!

```
public string language = "en";
```

And you should also upon opening any new Form  say form7

- add it to the list and
- call the ChangeLanguage( form7, language )

You should think about keeping the list of forms uptodate by removing closed forms from it.
If you make it a public property the closing form can remove itself from it, if it has a reference to your main form..

Comment: I don't understand. It should change be ChangeLanguage(this,"en");?
and ChangeLanguage method change to your code?

Comment: Yes, that is 'this' for the current window, and if you want to change other windows, then a reference to them. (You were asking about many forms!) And the language string should of course depend on the menu choice.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should set the language of your application in your start-up code.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-cn");
```

In .Net 4.5, there is also a new property called `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`. You can use it to set the default culture for all new threads.

If neither is applicable to your usage scenario, create a `BaseLangForm` class, which derives from `Form`, and call your `ChangeLanguage` method from the `OnLoad` event. All your forms must derive from `BaseLangForm` from the point forward.